# Need help with A record

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns-servers

I have a webhost with built-in domain petasos.000webhostapp.com. I have a custom domain bo-web.be with full DNS control. I'm looking on how to configure an A record to link the custom domain to my 000webhost website. I did this via a CNAME record but when visiting the site, the address bar still shows the 000webhostapp domain name and not my custom domain name. So I have the wrong primary domain.
I don't seem to find the correct IP to add in the A record? Thanks for the help here. U are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 000webhost offers free web hosting some limitations should be expected and this is one of those cases. You will most likely run into more limitations somewhere down the line.

*A records are not supported by 000webhost and the only methods to use a custom domain are:*

- Name Servers Method

  - Changing your existing name servers to `ns01.000webhost.com` and `ns02.000webhost.com`
- CNAME Method

  - Add cname and point to `your-website.000webhostapp.com`

If you've tried using the CNAME method and it redirects to your `example.000webhostapp.com` then it is likely because you have some redirect in the .htaccess file or your content management system needs updating.

Take WordPress as a good example... If I install on ExampleA.com and duplicate the site over to ExampleB.com, visiting ExampleB.com will redirect to ExampleA.com, why? because I've not told WordPress the new domain.

Comment: Hey Simon. Thank you for the answer. I'll look into my Wordpress settings later on to see if I can update my domain here. If I decide to pay for the hosting, you think it will be possible to use the A record instead?

Comment: Most paid hosting services will allow A records.